# vba macro to use vlookup

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to fetch the value using a vba macro and vlookup in excel. Expected value is the value from "hiveCatalog" sheet but actual result is "N/A"

When i try normal vlookup in excel, i do get the expected value.

Below is the code - written to update a specific column in the first sheet using the value from another sheet.

```
Sub **addVlookUpColumn**()

 Dim Row As Long
 Dim Clm   As Long
 Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet, Sheet2 As Worksheet

 Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Attributesstagingdirectload")
 Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hiveCatalog")

Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A11000")
Table2 = Sheet2.Range("A3:A11000")
Row = Sheet1.Range("D2").Row
Clm = Sheet2.Range("D2").Column

For Each cl In Table1
 Sheet1.Cells(Row, Clm) = Application.VLookup(c1, Table2, 1, False)
  Row = Row + 1
Next cl
```

End Sub

Do let me know where i am going wrong

Below image contains the column header of both the sheets and sheet names
[image]

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I get "#N/A" as output in cell

Comment: What is the point of a VLOOKUP on a single column range?

Comment: to check its existence in the other sheet

Comment: @rakeshsharma  , May I Ask you to leave me some feedbacks on the answer I proposed ? If it answers to your needs May I ask you to accept my answer :  [look here to see how to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set where `table2` is

You can give this a try if `hiveCatalog` is where the table is located.

```
Sheet1.Cells(Row, Clm) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Cells(Row, Clm) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, Worksheets("hiveCatalog").Table2, 1, False))
```